# How to fix systemctl with interactive authentication?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, ansible, systemctl

I have an ansible playbook to configure jenkins , this playbook is run as a part of cloud-init-script.

But its failing during jenkins restart. Can anyone pls let me know what interactive authentication its asking for and how i should fix this?

Version:
ansible==2.9.6
jenkins_version: 2.176.3

code:

```
- name: Restart Jenkins
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: restarted

- name: Wait for Jenkins to start up
  uri:
    url: http://localhost:8080
    user: "{{ jenkins_admin_username }}"
    password: "{{ jenkins_admin_password }}"
    force_basic_auth: true
    status_code: 200
    timeout: 5
  register: jenkins_service_status
  # Keep trying for 5 mins in 5 sec intervals
  retries: 60
  delay: 5
  until: >
     'status' in jenkins_service_status and
     jenkins_service_status['status'] == 200
```

error:

```
TASK [master : Restart Jenkins] ************************************************
task path: /opt/ihr-kopsfather/ansible-ihr-kopsfather/roles/master/tasks/restart_jenkins.yml:2
<127.0.0.1> ESTABLISH LOCAL CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'echo ~root && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c '( umask 77 && mkdir -p "` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829 `" && echo ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829="` echo /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829 `" ) && sleep 0'
Using module file /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ansible/modules/system/systemd.py
<127.0.0.1> PUT /root/.ansible/tmp/ansible-local-19289oaudtdeg/tmprianjznn TO /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829/AnsiballZ_systemd.py
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'setfacl -m u:jenkins:r-x /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829/ /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829/AnsiballZ_systemd.py && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'sudo -H -S -n  -u jenkins /bin/sh -c '"'"'echo BECOME-SUCCESS-egbsbalzblxddrdjyadziewvzilaaacg ; /usr/bin/python3 /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829/AnsiballZ_systemd.py'"'"' && sleep 0'
<127.0.0.1> EXEC /bin/sh -c 'rm -f -r /var/tmp/ansible-tmp-1597803601.9555757-44587295762829/ > /dev/null 2>&1 && sleep 0'
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "daemon_reexec": false,
            "daemon_reload": false,
            "enabled": null,
            "force": null,
            "masked": null,
            "name": "jenkins",
            "no_block": false,
            "scope": null,
            "state": "restarted",
            "user": null
        }
    },
    "msg": "Unable to restart service jenkins: Failed to restart jenkins.service: Interactive authentication required.\nSee system logs and 'systemctl status jenkins.service' for details.\n"
```

systemctl details:

```
sudo systemctl status jenkins.service
● jenkins.service - LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/jenkins; generated)
   Active: active (exited) since Wed 2020-08-19 02:18:09 UTC; 8min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/jenkins.service

Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time...
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 jenkins[27353]: Correct java version found
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 jenkins[27353]:  * Starting Jenkins Automation Server jenkins
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 su[27402]: Successful su for jenkins by root
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 su[27402]: + ??? root:jenkins
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 su[27402]: pam_unix(su:session): session opened for user jenkins by (uid=0)
Aug 19 02:18:08 ip-10-23-11-7 su[27402]: pam_unix(su:session): session closed for user jenkins
Aug 19 02:18:09 ip-10-23-11-7 jenkins[27353]:    ...done.
Aug 19 02:18:09 ip-10-23-11-7 systemd[1]: Started LSB: Start Jenkins at boot time.
```

Comment: with which user is ansible logging into the box to do the restart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most likely you are using a user to log into the target that is not allowed to perform these `systemctl` actions. So you may need to add `become: true` to your task (see the [documentation on become](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/become.html#using-become)):

```
- name: Restart Jenkins
  become: true
  service:
    name: jenkins
    state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0):

`task:`
`become: yes`
`- name: Restart Jenkins`
`service:`
`name: jenkins`
`state: stopped`

`- name: Restart Jenkins`
`service:`
`name: jenkins`
`state: started`

**Note : please check indentation.**

If You want to `start/stop` services u can also mention `become=yes` at starting of the script so it will not asked you to add manually at all sides where you want to start/stop service in same file.